# How to remove Heading Lines from output of netstat command?

Tags: c#, cmd, command, netstat

I am using C# language and I don't know from where should I start .
As we all know when we run **netstat** command. The output we see in the command prompt is like:

```
Active Connections


Proto  Local Address    Foreign Address     State          PID

TCP    0.0.0.1:123      0.0.0.1:0           LISTENING      112
TCP    0.0.0.1:125      0.0.0.1:0           LISTENING      152
```

I want to remove those first two lines :

1. Active Connections
2. Proto Local Address Foreign Address State PID

How can I do this ?
Can I implement this in code, I am using C# language ?

Comment: Why do you want to run netstat? you can access same data more easily with c# : See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899948/netstat-focus-on-find-port

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please provide a [mcve] of your own coding attempts!

Answer (score 3):

You need to count your heading lines as mine is only 4 lines

then simply change your netstat call to

```
netstat | more +4
```

and should only see

```
TCP    0.0.0.1:123      0.0.0.1:0           LISTENING      112
TCP    0.0.0.1:125      0.0.0.1:0           LISTENING      152
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can run a CmdCommand and get the output like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results):

```cs
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "netstat";
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

After the command is executed (needs a bit of time) you can manipulate the output:

```cs
output = output.Replace("Active Connections", "");
output = output.Replace("ProtoX", "");
output = output.Replace("Foreign Address", "");
output = output.Replace("State", "");
output = output.Replace("PID", "");

Console.WriteLine(output);
```